# Select foreign key inside insert statement Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, .net-core, oracle19c

I was using MySQL in my .NET Core project and now I've just switched to Oracle 19c. I had a big insert job that was splitted into chunks, each one processed by one transaction. Those insert statements were related. I mean, first I insert the parent row and then the child row with the relationship like this:

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (NAME, DESCRIPTION, UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER) 
            VALUES ('PARENT NAME', 'THIS IS THE PARENT', 1);
INSERT INTO CHILD (NAME, DESCRIPTION, PARENTID) 
            VALUES ('CHILD ONE', 'NEWBORN CHILD', 
                        (SELECT ID 
                        FROM PARENT 
                        WHERE UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = 1));
```

That worked right on MySQL but not in Oracle, it returns a "Number not valid" error. Is there a way to do that in Oracle or a method to get last inserted row id or something like that? The Parent ID is an autoincrement sequence so I don't now the value prior execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably help if you

- posted tables' description
- didn't post your own interpretation of Oracle error messages. They have their codes so you should have posted that, so that we'd exactly know what's going on. Because, there's no "Number not valid" error.

I made up my own example. As my database is 11gXE which doesn't support identity columns (auto-generated), I created a sequence and a trigger which serve the same purpose; disregard that.

Tables:

```
SQL> create table parent
  2    (id                number constraint pk_par primary key,
  3     name              varchar2(20),
  4     description       varchar2(20),
  5     unique_identifier number
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seqpar;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_par
  2    before insert on parent
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := nvl(:new.id, seqpar.nextval);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create table child
  2    (name             varchar2(20),
  3     description      varchar2(20),
  4     parentid         number constraint fk_chpar references parent (id)
  5    );

Table created.
```

Inserting rows, just as you did:

```
SQL> insert into parent (name, description, unique_identifier)
  2    values ('parent name', 'this is the parent', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into child (name, description, parentid)
  2    values ('child one', 'newborn child',
  3            (select id from parent where unique_identifier = 1));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

As you can see, no error if it is done properly.

---

So, what might be wrong with your code? I suspect at least one column - which is supposed to accept numeric values - is being inserted a string. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('A');
insert into test values ('A')
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL>
```

`ORA-01722: invalid number` is the closest to what you described as "Number not valid".

---

If that's not the case, then do as I told you up there, in those 2 bullets.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the problem was indeed with other column and the difference about production and development nls instances. There is a binary_double column and in pre it was accepting 12.5 as a valid number but production was only accepting numbers like 12,5. There was a bad configuration on nls_number_characters. This is the right answer. Thanks

Comment: I see. Great, I'm glad you found the culprit. Thank you for letting us know.